# Is it possible to target the Actionbar Menu Button on lower API levels <14?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

We are building an app that is (still) targeted at API Level 8, but we make use of the compatibility package. Because of the specs we cannot target level 14. On a new device (HTC One X) the menu button of the ActionBar is visible below the app. Is there a way to disable or hide that button?

Answer (score 4):

try reading about the [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/), it's a compatibility library for implementing action bar in lower SDK version.

Comment: Really like the suggestions of compatibility packages, sadly I haven't had the chance to test it out yet. From what I've read I don't think this will solve my problem, as it's not the action bar I want in Gingerbread, but I want to get rid of it in ICS, since the app is built with the level 10 API. But when I get the chance I will conduct an experiment and will you know if it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [ActionBarCompat](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ActionBarCompat/index.html). It's pure Android  :-)

Comment: Sherlock is also pure android, its pretty much a backport and definetly worth investing in, rolling your own (using the compat sample) gets tricky supporting the more advanced action bar features

Comment: @IanWarwick ABS also uses Apache License 2. Thanks  :-)  If I need more features, I'll go get it.